# Issues related to plots in pattern recognition(Part1)

Tags: matlab, pattern-recognition

I cannot follow `crossval()` & `cvpartition()` function given in MATLAB documentation [crossval()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/crossval.html;jsessionid=059d83fef038391717457e94df71). What goes in the parameter and how would it help to compare performance and accuracy of different classifiers. Would be obliged if a simpler version of it is provided here.

Comment: You are asking 3 quite independent questions. Please understand this site is not only to help you, but also to help others in the future when they will have similar questions. So the questions should be well organized and as descriptive as possible. I'd recommend to split your question to 3 different ones. You don't have to pay money for questions! And you will have 3 times more chances to increase your reputation.

Comment: Corrected the Question,thank you. Please have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's work on Example 2 from [CROSSVAL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/crossval.html#brx09ql-497) documentation.

```
load('fisheriris');
y = species;
X = meas;
```

Here we loaded the data from example mat-file and assigned variable to `X` and `y`. `meas` amtrix contains different measurements of iris flowers and `species` are tree classes of iris, what we are trying to predict with the data.

Cross-validation is used to train a classifier on the same data set many times. Basically at each iteration you split the data set to training and test data. The proportion is determined by k-fold. For example, if `k` is 10, 90% of the data will be used for training, and the rest 10% - for test, and you will have 10 iterations. This is done by [CVPARTITION](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/cvpartition.html) function.

```
cp = cvpartition(y,'k',10); % Stratified cross-validation
```

You can explore `cp` object if you type `cp.` and press *Tab*. You will see different properties and methods. For example, `find(cp.test(1))` will show indices of the test set for 1st iteration.

Next step is to prepare prediction function. This is probably where you had the main problem. This statement create function handle using anonymous function. `@(XTRAIN, ytrain,XTEST)` part declare that this function has 3 input arguments. Next part `(classify(XTEST,XTRAIN,ytrain))` defines the function, which gets training data `XTRAIN` with known `ytrain` classes and predicts classes for `XTEST` data with generated model. (Those data are from `cp`, remember?)

```
classf = @(XTRAIN, ytrain,XTEST)(classify(XTEST,XTRAIN,ytrain));
```

Then we are running CROSSVAL function to estimate missclassification rate (mcr) passing the complete data set, prediction function handle and partitioning object `cp`.

```
cvMCR = crossval('mcr',X,y,'predfun',classf,'partition',cp)
cvMCR =
    0.0200
```

Still have questions?

Comment: good explanation :) is it so hard for the developers to make ONE well explained example in the matlab help x)